# Почему не работает?(PyTelebot)

Tags: python, telebot

Что не так в части кода телеграмм бота?
Всё работает ДО **def send_weather(message):** а дальше(по задумке) пользователь вводит название города, бот ему отвечает что и как в этом городе. Но ничего не происходит, если нажать кнопку "Узнать погоду", то бот попросит опять ввести город и так по кругу.

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
import telebot
from telebot import types

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'  
owm = OWM('мой токен', config_dict)
bot = telebot.TeleBot("мой токен")
owm.supported_languages

#ЗДЕСЬ ПОСЛЕ КОМАНДЫ /START ВЫХОДИТ ПРИВЕТСТВИЕ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ И СПРАШИВАЕТ ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    sticker = open('static/sticker.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sticker)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Узнать погоду")
    
    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, {0.first_name}! \n Я - <b>{1.first_name}</b> бот, который поможет тебе узнать погоду в любом городе!\n Что ты хочешь сделать?".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def weather(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Узнать погоду':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Хорошо, {0.first_name} \nВведи название интересующего тебя города".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me))
#ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ ВВОДИТ НАЗВАНИЕ ГОРОДА И БОТ ЕМУ ОТВЕЧАЕТ ПО ПОГОДЕ
            bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
            def send_weather(message):
                mgr = owm.weather_manager()
                observation = mgr.weather_at_place( message.text )
                w = observation.weather
                temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]

                answer = " В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status + "\n"
                answer += "Температура сейчас около " + str((round(temp))) + "\n\n"
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id , answer)
bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

А если убрать всё, оставить только такой код, пользователь вводит просто название города и функция работает) Что не так в первом коде??(

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
import telebot

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'  
owm = OWM('токен', config_dict)
bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен", parse_mode=None)
owm.supported_languages



@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_weather(message):
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place( message.text )
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]

    answer = " В городе " + message.text + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status + "\n"
    answer += "Температура сейчас около " + str((round(temp))) + "\n\n"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id , answer)

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Почитай документацию на тему next_step_handler, очень поможет и упростит жизнь
https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py